# Laravel Scope with join query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What im trying to do is to make this join into a scope function

```
$workorders =\DB::table('users')->leftjoin('work_orders','users.id','=','work_orders.user_id')->select('users.id','users.name','users.email','users.status','work_orders.cod','work_orders.deadline'->where('users.id','=','1');    
$workorders = $workorders->get();
```

This is what I've tried with no success...

```
public function scopeOrders($query){
        return $query->join('work_orders','users.id','=','work_orders.user_id')
        ->select('users.id','users.name','users.email','users.status','work_orders.cod','work_orders.deadline')
        ->where('users.id','=','1');
    }
```

Expected result using the scope in a query

```
$usersWO = User::Orders()->get();
```

Comment: Do you have any error or something ? you need to use scopes with lowercase, try : `User::orders()->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between `$workorders = $workorders->get();` and `$usersWO = User::Orders()->get();` is the output format. They both are bug-free.

A `dd()` on the former outputs a collection of stdClass objects with record values as properties.:

[image]

A `dd()` on the latter outputs a collection of models:

[image]

To modify the output of the second to look exactly like the first, you'll have to modify the client code since scopes return collections of models.

```php
$usersWO = User::Orders()->get()->map(function ($user) {
    return (object) $user->getAttributes();
});
```